# Views php field or filter to a file or module

Tags: views, theming, security

If I already have a view with a php filter or a php field, in drupal 7, how can I convert my whole view into a page? (prevent code injections or other security risks)
What is the right way to resolve this?
Writing a module or a tpl.php file?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here

Custom Views Field Handler
https://kalamuna.atlassian.net/wiki/display/KALA/Custom+Views+Field+Handler

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/98354)

Comment: Well, i am still working on my solution.
Currently i have a php field in a view, and i want to use my own custom module with a view handler to delete that php field.
The link gives me some idea of what i need to do, but still no results.
Once i achieve what i want i'll write it here as a solution.